# How would I calculate the number of pay days before a date?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working on a budget spreadsheet and I'd like to calculate the number of pay periods before a certain date (including that date if it's a pay day). I'm not really sure how to begin.

My pay periods are always the same length of time, every other Friday. I was thinking I would somehow enter in a pay date, and from there the formula could count the number of pay days from today until another date.

As an example, let's say today is 05/22/2016. My next pay date is 06/03/2016. If I have something due on 12/13/2016, I want the formula to state that there are 14 pay days between now and then. If I were to recalculate from 06/04/2016, then it should say 13.

**How can I count the number of pay days between two dates in Excel?**

Answer (score 1):

Here's the equation:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(B2)=B1, INT((DAYS(B3,B2)/B4)-1), INT(DAYS(B3,B2)/B4))
```

Description:

- The day of the week you get paid needs to be put    in cell `B1`
  encoded as Sunday=1, Monday=2, .. ,Saturday=7.
- The cell `B2` should have the starting date.
- The cell `B3` should have the end date.
- How often you get paid in days needs to go cell `B4` (i.e. once
  per week=7,every other week=14).
- This will not count the current payday if the start day is a payday. To remove that, just use `=INT(DAYS(B3,B2)/B4))`.

Answer (score 1):

The following formula will count all paydays between the start and end date. It will work whether the start or end date fall on a payday or not:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B1-ROW(INDIRECT(B3&":"&B4))=CEILING(B1-ROW(INDIRECT(B3&":"&B4)),B2)))
```

- Sample Payday - `B1` represents any date that falls on a payday, your first payday for example. *Be aware,* **this formula will count paydays that fall before your sample pay day** *so if you use your first payday, ensure your start date is on or after your first payday.*
- Period - `B2` represents the pay period, 7 for weekly or 14 for biweekly.
- Start Date - `B3` The first day of the date range you are querying.
- End Date - `B4` The last day of the date range you are querying.

---

Example:

- First payday `B1 = 5/8/19`
- Period `B2 = 14`
- Start Date `B3 = 9/1/2019`
- End Date = `B4 = 5/2/2022`

The formula would return 69 because there are 69 paydays between 9/1/2019 and 5/2/2022.

Comment: Please explain how this works. … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

There are functions like `WEEKNUM()` and `WEEKDAY()`, and you can just subtract dates form each other to get number of days in between.

Your request is not clear enough for me to give a formula, but for example `TODAY()-<somecell>` gives you the number of days between them, and `WEEKNUM(TODAY())-WEEKNUM(<somecell>)` gives the number of weeks between them. Experiment with those.

Comment: As an example, let's say today is 05/22/2016. My next pay date is 06/03/2016. If I have something due on 12/13/2016, I want the formula to state that there are 14 pay days between now and then.

If I were to recalculate from 06/04/2016, then it should say 13.

Comment: Thanks for the tips though, I'll try to investigate that!

Answer (score 0):

You can't without more information.

For example, if the two dates are:

- 5/11/2016
- 5/18/2016

There is a single Friday between these two dates.  If you get paid every  other Friday, how could anyone tell if that Friday *(5/13/2016)* is a payday or not ???

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. That's why I think the ultimate answer has two parts to it. If I specify a single pay date, we should be able to figure out if any given Friday is a pay day or not. Yes?

Comment: @ardavis  you are **100%** correct!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
=INT((<next_payday>-<final_date>)/14)
```

with your example:

```
=INT(("13/12/16"-"3/6/16")/14)
```

the `/14` at the end represents the frequency with which you get paid (every 14 days)